# How to exit XCUItest without killing the app?

Tags: ios, testing, xctest, xcuitest

For some reason, we have to use XCUItest to start the target app, and just make it stay in the screen.

In order to make it be kept on the screen, we've tried to add `sleep` at the end of the case, as:

```
for _ in 0..<10 {
    // some case here
    tapCoordinate(x y)
    sleep(7200)
}
```

But it seems that xctest make the got stuck:
[image]

I was wondering if there's any idea to just start the app and leave xctest?

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re looking for a bit more and what your setup is? I’m initially thinking that setting a breakpoint might meet your needs; a sleep is going to pause the app, but a breakpoint will allow you to manipulate it and won’t timeout.

Comment: @MikeCollins Thanks for your quick reply. My case is really weird: I'm trying to run some auto test inside a custom keyboard itself(Not clicking by XCTest). However, iOS seems will remove the keyboard after 1~3 hours after the test started. I am figuring out if we could use XCTest to start a mock app and trigger the keyboard. If the keyboard has been removed, use XCTest to add it back and trigger the test again.

Comment: This seems pretty feasible with some sort of loop that looks for the keyboard prior to typing and brings it up if it’s not found.

Comment: @MikeCollins Yes, I agree with you. The case is we are using `tapCoordinate(x y)` to  trigger the keyboard to start testing itself. But the `sleep(7200)` would block the keyboard. I am not sure if we could use xctest just to bring it up, `tapCoordinate(x y)` and leave it there.

Comment: @pvd As you said, `sleep` will block the UI and your custom keyboard tests wont run when the system is in idle state. Try to include a timer inside your custom keyboard tests. For every particular secs(say 15 secs), trigger some action/notification from your custom keyboard tests to tap some button in the application status bar (like `XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard").statusBars.otherElements["Cellular"].tap()`).